# Adding to an int inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, int

I keep trying to add (many times) +1 to a number (the number is zero) already in an array which is zero but it is not working.

```
int i=0;//var for arrays
int [] countArray = new int[10];


/////////////////////
//__________ ask for values --------------

System.out.println("Hello please enter the number you would" +
        " like to be sorted separated by commas. \n" +
        "Example: \" 2,3,5,83,2 \".\t only use" +
        " commas. to separate numbers\n");


//-----------   save values -----
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String allInput = scan.nextLine();//single string object with all input

String [] arr = allInput.split(",");//string array that holds all values
//as String
int [] numbersArray =new int[arr.length] ;//numbers

for ( String w: arr){//change Strings to Int
    numbersArray[i]= Integer.valueOf(arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

//**__** set all number in count to zero because necessary

```
i=0;
for ( int x: countArray){//set all numbers to zero
countArray[i]=0;        

i++;

} //everything zeroed


i=0;
```

This works now, thank you guys:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++){


if (numbersArray[x] >=10 && numbersArray[x] <=100)  {  
countArray[(numbersArray[x]-1)/10]++;}
else{

    if (numbersArray[x] >=0 && numbersArray[x] <=10)
    {
 countArray[1 -1]++;}
}



}
```

Comment: a few sysos and debugging will help.

Comment: Change each one of your `for` loops to a simple `for (int i=0; i<xxx.length; i++)`. There is nothing to gain with the way you're doing it, and it just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Also, in that last `for` loop, you can simply calculate some `int index = (numbersArray[i]-1)/10`, and after verifying it's between 0 and 9, use it with `countArray[index]++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a for-each loop to edit all the values, try to iterate through them using a standard for loop. Here is a shorthand version of what you wrote. Try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numbersArray.length; x++){
    countArray[(numbersArray[x]-1)/10]++;
}
```

Comment: You should start from `x=0`, and you should use `(numbersArray[x]-1)/10` inside this loop.

Comment: And you should probably make sure that `(numbersArray[x]-1)/10` is a legal index (i.e., between 0 and `countArray.length-1`).

Comment: I used the loop above and it fixed everything,thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, just don't forget about barak's comment, make sure you check for bounds.